# Can we read swf file in java?

Tags: java, file, servlets, flash

We are using flash player to play swf files in our java application.So we tried to play static video its working fine.But we tried to play from file system using java servlet but we are not able to play the video.My doubt is:

1.Can we read the swf file using java File I/O streams?
2.If yes for first question,please tell us how to get this done(if any one has idea please share with us)?

We are using same code in the following url:

http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code how to play swf using flash in Java. I need help

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps for you:
http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/
http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2006/08/01/lightweight-swf-header-reader-java/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.